# QToolBar size and alignment with hidden actions

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm adding a toolbar to a widget, and dynamically hiding actions (they are also used in context menus). I'm encountering some problem with alignment/size. In the image below, Test 1 is "correct", and I want the other two to have only the "C" button, right-aligned (as in Test 3, but without the extra left space).

[image]

The code shows my attempt. Test 2 simply uses `.setVisible(False)` on the action A and B, while Test 3 does the same *and* adds a couple of empty `QLabel` on the left (if I add only one), the C does not end up right-aligned. It looks like `QToolBar` wants a minimum of 3 buttons or something.

Any idea how to fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()

    stylesheet = 'QToolButton{padding: 0; margin: 0} QToolBar{border: 1px solid black}'

    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    a = QAction('A', self)
    b = QAction('B', self)
    c = QAction('C', self)
    toolbar = QToolBar()
    toolbar.addAction(a)
    toolbar.addAction(b)
    toolbar.addAction(c)
    toolbar.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(QLabel('Test 1'))
    hbox.addStretch(1)
    hbox.addWidget(toolbar)
    group = QGroupBox()
    group.setLayout(hbox)
    layout.addWidget(group)

    a = QAction('A', self)
    b = QAction('B', self)
    c = QAction('C', self)
    toolbar = QToolBar()
    toolbar.addAction(a)
    toolbar.addAction(b)
    toolbar.addAction(c)
    a.setVisible(False)
    b.setVisible(False)
    toolbar.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(QLabel('Test 2'))
    hbox.addStretch(1)
    hbox.addWidget(toolbar)
    group = QGroupBox()
    group.setLayout(hbox)
    layout.addWidget(group)

    a = QAction('A', self)
    b = QAction('B', self)
    c = QAction('C', self)
    toolbar = QToolBar()
    toolbar.addWidget(QLabel(''))
    toolbar.addWidget(QLabel(''))
    toolbar.addAction(a)
    toolbar.addAction(b)
    toolbar.addAction(c)
    a.setVisible(False)
    b.setVisible(False)
    toolbar.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(QLabel('Test 3'))
    hbox.addStretch(1)
    hbox.addWidget(toolbar)
    group = QGroupBox()
    group.setLayout(hbox)
    layout.addWidget(group)

    layout.addStretch(1)

    widget = QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(layout)

    self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically hide actions in a QToolbar, you cannot use `setVisible(False)` on the action since it will only "hide" the action from view but the button is inherently still there which is why you have the extra white space. Even though the action is hidden, there is still padding from a hidden object which gives you the undesired empty space. Similarly, when you add empty `QLabels`, this "hidden" widget also leaves white space since the physical area of the widget is still there.

Considering this, a solution is to remove the action from the `QToolbar` using `removeAction()`. This way, the actual object will be removed from the layout so there is no white space. Here's an example that shows how to add and remove actions in a `QToolbar` using handlers. You can check what objects are in the `Qtoolbar` with `.actions()` and depending on what action you want to remove, you can simply pass this to `removeAction()`. I'll leave it up to you to implement error handling when there are no more actions to add or no more actions to remove.

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.stylesheet = 'QToolButton{padding: 0; margin: 0} QToolBar{border: 1px solid black}'

        self.main_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.a = QAction('A', self)
        self.b = QAction('B', self)
        self.c = QAction('C', self)

        self.action_table = {1: self.a,
                             2: self.b,
                             3: self.c
        }

        self.test1_toolbar = QToolBar()
        self.test1_toolbar.addAction(self.a)
        self.test1_toolbar.addAction(self.b)
        self.test1_toolbar.addAction(self.c)
        self.test1_toolbar.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet)
        self.test1_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.test1_hbox.addWidget(QLabel('Test 1'))
        self.test1_hbox.addStretch(1)
        self.test1_hbox.addWidget(self.test1_toolbar)
        self.test1_group = QGroupBox()
        self.test1_group.setLayout(self.test1_hbox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.test1_group)

        self.test2_toolbar = QToolBar()
        self.test2_toolbar.addAction(self.a)
        self.test2_toolbar.addAction(self.b)
        self.test2_toolbar.addAction(self.c)
        self.test2_toolbar.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet)
        self.test2_add_button = QPushButton('Add')
        self.test2_add_button.clicked.connect(self.test2_add_action)
        self.test2_remove_button = QPushButton('Remove')
        self.test2_remove_button.clicked.connect(self.test2_remove_action)
        self.test2_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.test2_hbox.addWidget(QLabel('Test 2'))
        self.test2_hbox.addStretch(1)
        self.test2_hbox.addWidget(self.test2_toolbar)
        self.test2_group = QGroupBox()
        self.test2_group.setLayout(self.test2_hbox)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.test2_group)

        self.test3_toolbar = QToolBar()
        self.test3_toolbar.addAction(self.a)
        self.test3_toolbar.addAction(self.b)
        self.test3_toolbar.addAction(self.c)
        self.test3_toolbar.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet)
        self.test3_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.test3_hbox.addWidget(QLabel('Test 3'))
        self.test3_hbox.addStretch(1)
        self.test3_hbox.addWidget(self.test3_toolbar)
        self.test3_group = QGroupBox()
        self.test3_group.setLayout(self.test3_hbox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.test3_group)

        self.layout.addStretch(1)

        self.widget = QWidget()

        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.layout,0,0,1,1)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.test2_add_button,0,1,1,1)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.test2_remove_button,0,2,1,1)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.show()

    def test2_add_action(self):
        objects = len(self.test2_toolbar.actions())
        self.test2_toolbar.addAction(self.action_table[objects + 1])

    def test2_remove_action(self):
        objects = len(self.test2_toolbar.actions())
        self.test2_toolbar.removeAction(self.action_table[objects])

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'd like to add a small note about this: with this implementation (which I concur, is not the standard way of dealing with QToolBars), there can be some discrepancy with some styles. For example, Oxygen style creates an empty margin on the right of the tool bar layout if excacly *two* buttons appear (1st button width + extension button width - 2nd button width); I *believe* that's actually a QStyle bug, but it might be worth keeping track of that. For similar cases, using `QToolBar > QToolButton { min-width: 0px; }` **could** be a solution, but some more digging might still be needed.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the extra white space is to the right of C, if the "hidden objects" are to the left. Or why when adding the empty labels the white space becomes smaller (the same hidden actions are still present). If I have to go through each toolbar and menu and find where the action is used, I might as well just `QToolButton` directly... (ETA. OK, the previous comment helps, since I'm using Oxygen.)